# Iptables : forwarding SSH traffic according destination IP

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, nat

I have 2 servers : One that receives connections from outside my LAN and another (inside the LAN) that I aim to access from outside via ssh.
There are prerequisites : I can't access to my SSH services with an other port than 22 ; of course, the first server have to be accessible with SSH too.

I created a network alias for the entry server :

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.254
        # DNS directives


allow-hotplug eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
        address 192.168.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.254
        # DNS directives
```

My strategy is : with the firewall, forward all the SSH connections to the second IP address to the server inside the LAN.
So, i executed theses commands to configure the firewall (172.16.1.1 is the IP address of the server inside the LAN) :

```
# iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.16.1.1 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# iptables -v -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 192.168.1.2 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.1.1:22
```

When I try to connect via SSH to the network alias (192.168.1.2), from a machine that have access to my "firewall" server, it doesn't work :

```
# ssh -v root@192.168.1.2
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.14.15 [192.168.14.15] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.14.15 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.14.15 port 22: Connection timed out
```

On the machine I try to connect to, the SSH log (/var/log/auth.log) says nothing...

In your opinion, what is the problem ? (hoping I was clear enough...)

**EDIT :**

I logged the iptables activity (on the FORWARD chain, for the tcp protocol, with the log level Debug). During the ssh connection try, I have this output (6 times the same for one connection try) :

```
Mar 21 10:15:53 server1 kernel: [241152.008342] [ ### IPTABLES ### ] IN=eth0 OUT=eth0 MAC=0f:a0:12:61:ac:b8:10:55:5e:90:a3:1a:38:01 SRC=192.168.1.3 DST=172.16.1.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=48895 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53677 DPT=22 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

On the target server, the packets seem to be well received : after having configured logging on iptables too (which accepts all), I have that output :

```
Mar 21 10:31:58 server2 kernel: [11214102.440239] [ ### IPTABLES ### ] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=04:d0:5e:54:4a:8c:01:0d:24:1a:9f:d3:08:10 SRC=192.168.1.3 DST=172.16.1.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=21999 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53681 DPT=22 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

**EDIT 2 :**

According Laurentiu Roescu advices, I added theses rules to my "middle" machine :

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -o eth0 -s 172.16.1.1 -p tcp -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.2
# iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 172.16.1.1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: You need SNAT for 172.16.1.1 packets. And also to allow forwarding from 172.16.1.1 to 192.168.1.3

Comment: Have I correctly understood that only 192.168.1.1 has access to the 172.16.1.1? And for e.g. 192.168.1.3 doesn't have it, but should get it only through 192.168.1.1?

Comment: @ALex_hha Yes, that is.

Comment: In such case as @Laurentiu Roescu said you must SNAT all packets for the 172.16.1.1 on 192.168.1.1.

Comment: Have you configured the sshd on the middle machine to NOT listen on port 22 of the alias IP?

Comment: In the SNAT rule there is should be '-d 172.16.1.1 -j SNAT ...'

Answer (score 0):

The following rules should be enough

```
# iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.1.1:22
# iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 172.16.1.1 --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1
```

Check that forwarding has been enabled

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

If you have strict policy in FORWARD chain you should also allow forwarding to the 172.16.1.1

```
# iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.16.1.1 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```